# How to wire up a DropDownList to make AJAX calls to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET `DropDownList` server control on my page `Default.aspx`. I'm trying to handle the the selection change event (if using server events it was `SelectedIndexChanged` event) client side and make an AJAX call back to the server (I used to use UpdatePanels a few years back but want to just use `jQuery/ajax` to do this now).

I have the following simple method server side (following this example http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/):

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
  //Do some processing
}
```

I then have this JavaScript in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
         // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the control.
         $("<%= MyDDL.ClientID %>").click(function () {
               $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Default.aspx/MyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged",
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json"
               });
            });
            });
</script>
```

Here is the server control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyDDL" runat="server" Width="340px" />
```

As it stands this does not work. No error or anything. The method is never called no matter what I do to interact with my `DropDownList`.

I believe the issue is that the `click` JavaScript event is not the correct one to wire up to the control. I also tried `change` and that didn't work either. Basically what I want is when the selection has changed on the control, the script is called which in turn calls my server side method.

Can anyone assist on what I may be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Well you should definitely be using `change`. Can you throw a log statement into your change function to verify it's being called? If it is being called, head over to the network tab to see if the request is going through.

Comment: I just added the simple event handler that does nothing but an `alert` from this link: http://api.jquery.com/change/ and it still did not get called. Is `change` the correct one for sure?

Comment: It is definitely the right one...this isn't a dynamically generated element is it?

Comment: Got it working - please see my comments on the marked answer.

Comment: 1 character throwing the whole mix off, typical :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event instead of the click

Comment: I had made a late edit to my description and I tried that as well and it did not work. _"I also tried change and that didn't work either."_

Comment: put a break point in your code and see if your jquery selector is correct.

Comment: Just got it working - it was a 2 pronged issue. 1. the control had the incorrect syntax. It was missing the `#` symbol and should read: `'#<%= MyDDL.ClientID %>'` 2. It was indeed the `change` and not `click` event, but `change` was not working because the control ID was not proper in the 1st place.

Comment: yeah. Normally if you are getting no results (not even incorrect ones) on an event your selector is incorrect.