# How to bind a controls data using jQuery and Static Page Method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

Goal:  Call a server side method asynchronously from changing a dropdown to get data and populate a separate listbox *not* using UpdatePanels.

Currently I'm using a `static` ASP.NET page method asynchronously using `jQuery` and an `ajax` call as shown in this post ([How to wire up a DropDownList to make AJAX calls to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664397/how-to-wire-up-a-dropdownlist-to-make-ajax-calls-to-the-server)) and **it is** working well.

The whole purpose was to prevent using the `UpdatePanel` tangled mess that I had been in previous years and this seems to be a good alternative. What I didn't realize is that the page method has to be `static` and you *can not* access any of the page's controls or context. So trying to make this call from a dropdown selection to populate another control's data is not possible. I can't see the other controls.

So what I'd like to do before I give up and go back to updatepanels is try to do 1 of the following:

1. Have my static page method return a `json` string with my collection data that I then use in the original jQuery method wired up to the `change` method of the dropdown to populate the separate listbox.
2. Same as above but return a .NET `IList<>` or comparable if returning json is not a good idea.

Point is I want that static method to return the needed data to bind to my listbox control. However I don't know how to do this. Here is my current jQuery method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
         // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the control.
         $("<%= MyDDL.ClientID %>").click(function () {
               $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Default.aspx/MyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged",
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json"
               });
            });
            });
</script>
```

Here is the original dropdown:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyDDL" runat="server" Width="340px" />
```

Here is the control that needs populated based on the selection of the dropdown after calling the static method named `MyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" Width="340px" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

Here is my current static page method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass()
    var data = myClass.GetDataCollection()
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(data);
}
```

Is there a way to take this returned data and bind it in the jQuery method above? My bailout is to go back to using an `UpdatePanel` where my server-side method can access other controls, but I really do not want to do this.

Comment: I don't think you need to serialize output yourself, it is done auto.
Also in jQuery.ajax you just need to use "success" option to read the returned json

Comment: also it should be "#<%= MyDDL.ClientID %>"

Comment: @MichaelB. - Thanks. Do you have an example of the `success` option using my example and specifically using the returned result to populate an ASP.NET `ListBox` control?

Comment: Try using firebug to see the structure of returned json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was looking for a more complete exaample and have the solution working with the code below:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     MyDDL_OnChangeHandler();
  });

  function MyDDL_OnChangeHandler() {
     // Add the page method call as an change handler for the MyDDL DropDownList.
     // This will call the static page method, and use the returned results to populate the 'MyListBox' listbox control.
     $('#<%=MyDDL.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                 var val = $(this).val();
                 var text = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
                 var $lbxCtrl = $('#<%=MyListBox.ClientID %>');
           $lbxCtrl.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
           $lbxCtrl.empty();
           $lbxCtrl.append('<option value="0">< Loading Please Wait... ></option>');
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "Default.aspx/MyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              data: "{'ID':'" + val + "', 'Name':'" + text + "'}",
              success: function (data) {
                 $lbxCtrl.removeAttr('disabled');
                 $lbxCtrl.empty();
                 if (data.d == null) {
                    return;
                 }
                 $.each(data.d, function (i, data) {
                    $users.append('<option value="' + data.Value + '">' + data.FullName + ' (' +  adUser.data+ ')' +'</option>');
                 });
              },
              error: function () {
                 $lbxCtrl.empty();
                 $lbxCtrl.append('<option value="0">< Error Loading Data ></option>');
                 alert('Failed to retrieve data.');
              }
           });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript project called [jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) that may be what you need:

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/12/01/goodby-jquery-templates-hello-jsrender.aspx

Answer (score -1):

As Michael B mentioned in the comments, you can handle any data returned from the ajax call by using `success:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
         // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the control.
         $("#<%= MyDDL.ClientID %>").click(function () {
               $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Default.aspx/MyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged",
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(data) {
                       // do stuff with the "data" that is returned
                  },
                  error: function(data) {
                       // handle any errors here
                  }
               });
            });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: The issue is the most important example I needed is what was within the `success` parameter and this code example just lists `// do stuff`. I needed the `do stuff` part to fully answer my question.

Comment: Not entirely sure that needs a downvote, but fair enough. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Unfortunately downvotes are often taken as offensive, but they shouldn't be and are honestly probably not used enough. The answer as it stands did not answer my question, and therefore received a downvote. It more specifically was a 'half-answer' as the most important part wasn't clarified. Downvotes should always be followed by reasoning, and I provided that as well. If you improve your answer to answer the question, I'll certainly upvote it!

Comment: Not offended. I provided you with the direction of `success:` and `error:` and allowed you to figure out the "meat" of the `// do stuff`. The only thing I could do now to "improve" the answer is copy what you've already posted as the solution, which I don't feel is an accurate use of editing. Again, glad you got it working and I'm fine with the downvote.